# not able to create rails new application with mysql version 0.3.20

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I want to create new rails application (version 4.2.4) with mysql2 (version 0.3.20) but I am not able to create it ...

eg.

```
 rails new abc -d=mysql-0.3.20
 rails new abc -d=mysql -v=0.3.20
 rails new abc -d mysql -v '0.3.20'
 rails new abc -d mysql -v 0.3.20
```

I tried all above commands but it installs mysql2 0.4.1

**I want to create rails new app with mysql version 0.3.20**

thanks for help

Comment: I don't think you specify the version from command line.  You'd need to create a [template](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html) for that.

Comment: thanks for response .... is there any other option than templates ?

Comment: You can specify it in the Gemfile yourself each time.

Comment: you can create rails app `rails new abc` (default db would be sqlite) then modify gemfile and after installing bundle through `bundle install` set mysql DB from `config/database.yml` after that create your db ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2):

You cannot specify mysql version while creating new rails application. The only solution is using command `rails new app_name -d mysql` and after creating app specify mysql version in Gemfile.